# Using second form as "Please wait while..."-Info: Strange Appearance

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on a program, which accesses databases.
During the process of searching the LAN for hosts/instances, I want to display a second form on top of my main form, which indicates that the program is "working on it".
This works fine, I guess, but still, the appearance of the "Please wait.."-Form is broken.

[image: Notice, the upper left corner]

Here's how I am trying to handle it:

```
Private Sub Cbox_database_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbox_database.MouseClick
    Try
        Dim frmloading As New loading
        loading.Show()
        cbox_database.Items.Clear()
        loadInstances(cbox_database)
    Finally
        loading.Close()
        cbox_database.DroppedDown = True
    End Try
End Sub

Sub loadInstances(cbox As ComboBox)
    Dim dt As DataTable = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        cbox.Items.Add(String.Concat(dr("ServerName"), "\", dr("InstanceName")))
    Next
End Sub
```

Since I am a beginner, I am sure there is a far better way to do this. I am open for any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Your UI is not being updated because you have a blocking operation (loading data) on the same thread

Comment: `Refresh()` the Form after you have shown it. You should probably set the owner: `loading.Show(Me)`

Comment: @Jimi This kind of worked for me, still the position "Centerparent" isnt working.

Comment: Add `loading.Update()` to ensure that the child controls get a chance to paint themselves.  That gives you about 5 seconds, after which you can no longer ignore the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: Have you used `loading.Show(Me)`? If you set the `StartPosition` to `CenterScreen` of in the Designer, `frmloading` will be centered on its owner.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, that is exactly what I have done. The setting gets ignored completely

Comment: @HansPassant this did it for me. Thanks alot!

Comment: As alluded to by @HansPassant, you really ought to be doing the actual work in a secondary thread.  This may be of interest to you if you want to do this "properly": http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567